# Angular Material: md-icon not found

Tags: material-design, angular-material

I'm using material designe icon in an svg format.
When I try to display the icon in my html I get the error: 
"icon mdsize: A not found".

I saved all the icons in an svg file with all the paths.

My config.js file:

```
app.config(function($mdIconProvider){
    $mdIconProvider.iconSet('mdsize', 'fileSrc', 24);
 });
```

My svg file:

```
<g id="A">
    <path d="iconPath" fill="none"/>
    <path d="anotherPath"/>
</g>
```

My html:

```
<md-icon md-svg-icon="mdsize:A"></md-icon>
```

The md-icon tag is inside an md-list-item that is generated by ng-repeat.

Important to mention: There is another md-icon that is saved in the same svg file inside the md-list-item and it is shown on the html page. The way of presenting them is iddenticle so I don't see why the other icon won't show.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about svg but I've had a play and this works without errors.

fileSrc.txt

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <g id="A">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        angular.module("elcomaApp", ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
            .config(function($mdIconProvider){
                $mdIconProvider.iconSet('mdsize', 'fileSrc.txt', 204);
            })
            .controller("MainController", function() {

            });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="elcomaApp" ng-controller="MainController" ng-cloak>
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="mdsize:A"></md-icon>  
</body>
</html>
```

If I replace the content of fileSrc.txt with the following I also don't see any errors:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <g id="A">
       <path d="iconPath" fill="none"/>
       <path d="anotherPath"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Note: These files work with Firefox but Chrome shows a "Cross origin" error.